# ShellScript sync two folders

Tags: bash, shell

Hey Guys i am very new to this whole bash thing. 
I am trying to write a shell script which sync two folders. So in theory i have to list all files from folder one into an array and check if file in folder b exists. If not cp $file into folder b.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES="`/PATH/TO/ALL/FILES`"
function generateList {
    for file in "$FILES"
    do
        echo "$file"
    done

}
```

So maybe ou know a good tutorial what teaches the basics. :)

Comment: If you want to practice bash, fine, look at `man test` how to test if a file exists or not. However if you really want some more robust sync then use `rsync` at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into using rsync.

This link seems to have information that will help you along your way, if `man rsync` doesn't meet your documentation needs:

http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/using_rsync_keep_your_files_sync_0

Comment: Holy mother of god! Big thanks! That saved me a lot of time!!!

Comment: You're welcome! I felt bad only providing a link and a suggestion to check out the man page, but at the end of the day, I figured that you wanted to meet a need and not make your own wheel.

Comment: damn right! rsync was exactly what i have searched for…